# How to perform "complex" calculations in LaTeX/TikZ

Tags: latex, tikz

I expect this question has already been answered a thousand times, but I just cannot find a solution to my issue =(

I want to calculate some values in LaTeX (TikZ), some of which are lengths (e.g. 10 pt), some are not. As long as calculations are of very simple forms like `a*b+c` everything is fine, but if I need brackets like `(a+b)*(c+d)` LaTeX complains. Furthermore, if I have nested definitions, these are not solved as expected. Example:

```
\def\varA{1+2}
\def\varB{10}
% I want to calculate (1+2)*10 or 10*(1+2), respectively.
\def\varC{\varA*\varB} % evaluates to 21
\def\varD{\varB*\varA} % evaluates to 12
```

So basically my question is: **What is the correct (or recommended) way to do calculations in LaTeX?**

As a more realistic example, here is something I actually want to do and just can't:

```
% total height of my TikZ image
\def\myheight{20ex}
% five nodes shall be drawn as a stack
\def\numnodes{5}
% but there shall be some space at the top (like a 6th node)
\def\heightpernodeA{\myheight / (\numnodes + 1)} % fails whenever I want to use it
% workaround?
\def\numnodesplusone{\numnodes + 1}
\def\heightpernodeB{\myheight / \numnodesplusone} % fails for the reason explained above
```

Unfortunately I can not redefine \numnodes to be 6 as I use the variable for various calculations.

best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro` for more complex calculation. You'll need to remove the unit in `myheight` though:

```
% total height of my TikZ image
\def\myheight{20}
% five nodes shall be drawn as a stack
\def\numnodes{5}
% but there shall be some space at the top (like a 6th node)
\pgfmathsetmacro\heightpernodeA{\myheight / (\numnodes + 1)}
```

You can add the unit back when you use it: `\draw (0,0) -- ({\heightpernodeA ex},{1});`

Comment: This definitely pointed to the right direction.
I ended up using `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` for my stuff.

Comment: I don't know that one. What's the difference with `\pgfmathsetmacro`?

Comment: `\pgfmathsetmacro` can be used for raw calculations like `20 * (12 + 762)`, but you get in trouble if you try to use units (lengths) with this one. The only workaround is to append the length when using the macro like `\mymacro{}pt`. `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` is specifically designed to work with lengths, so you can do something like `20 * (12pt + 762cm)`. Internally every length value is transformed to pt. As a result, you always get the correct length and you even don't have to append the unit when using the macro.